# What is the difference between Master Site and Index.cshtml in MVC project with Razor views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

What is are differences between site.master and Index.cshtml in MVC project? In this tutorial: 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-10 I found reference to
`Site.master` but it is not explained.

Answer (score 2):

Master pages are part of ASP.NET WebForms and are the equivalent of Layout pages in Razor

Answer (score 0):

Master pages are also part of MVC, the razor engine uses Site.master.